# VB.NET ShowDialog Form not Ending

Tags: vb.net, forms, showdialog

I converted this app from VB6.  I have 2 forms. Form1 instantiates Form2 via a Menu Item.
I am having trouble getting Form2 to end when clicking close (X).  If Form2 is 'idle' it closes fine; but if I am in a loop processing anything all the events fire, but it continues processing in Form2. I've tried messing with Dispose, Close, Application.Exit, Application.ExitThread. My last attempt was creating my own event to fire back to Form1 and dispose Form2 -- and it hits it but Form2 is still running. What is the deal?  BTW if I use just Show vs ShowDialog -- Form2 just blinks and disappears.

```
Form1 does this
Dim f2 as Import
:
        Hide()
        f2 = New Import
        AddHandler f2.die, AddressOf killf2
        f2.ShowDialog(Me)
        Show()

Private Sub killf2()
        f2.Dispose()
        f2 = Nothing
End Sub

Form2

Public Event die()
Private Shadows Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Dispose()
        Close()
        e.Cancel = False
        RaiseEvent die()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got your events crossed.  You want form1, containing an instance of form2, to listen for form2's form_closing event.  Then you can set f2 = nothing.

Form1 should fully enclose form2.

here's an example:

```
Public Class MDIMain
    Private WithEvents _child As frmViewChild

    Friend Sub viewChildShow()
        _child = New frmViewChild
        _child.MdiParent = Me
        _child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        _child.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _child_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles _child.FormClosing
        _child = Nothing
    End Sub
```

don't add anything to form2, try

```
Dim f2 as Import
        Hide()
        f2 = New Import
        f2.ShowDialog(Me)
        Show()

Private Sub f2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles f2.FormClosing
        set f2 = nothing
End Sub
```

re: your comment
*it goes back to form2 and continues processing the next statement in the the click event handler*

that's a feature and it will cause this behavior.  you need to make sure me.close or close me is the last statement in form2, that there's nothing else to execute.

Comment: I just called the event Form1_FormClosing as I copied and pasted.  It actually handles MyBase.FormClosing -- for form2.  If that is not what you meant -- then how do I listen for form 2's form_closing event in form1 other than just raising an event and setting f2=nothing like I have done.  Thanks!

Comment: Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles f2.FormClosing
        f2.Dispose()
        f2.Close()
        f2 = Nothing
    End Sub

Comment: I just don't understand why the form doesn't end.  I did exactly what you have and after it hits the f2=nothing in form1 it goes back to form2 and continues processing the next statement in the the click event handler

Comment: One thing I did try and seemed to work was define a boolean quit and then in the Form1 event handler set quit to true.  In the loop if quit = true exit sub.  Is this the way to handle it????

Comment: Spoke too soon -- once I try to click that Form2 and start it up again I get that the process can't access a file because it is being used by another process

Answer (score 0):

What is this loop you speak of? The user interface (windows) is separate from any code that is running. In your class derived form Form, Code is allowed to run, both before the Form is created, and after the Form is destroyed. If the code tries to access user-interface objects then an exception might occur, but otherwise there is nothing stopping your code from running when there is no user interface.

If you want your "for" loop to exit then you must send it a signal somehow, e.g. by creating a boolean "quit" member variable. Set "quit=True" when your form closes, then have your "for" loop check whether it is true.